# File Not Found - django_debug_toolbar

Tags: django, static, django-debug-toolbar

I am trying to get djange_debug_toolbar to work in my django application. I am unable to get it to show up on my pages.  Looking into the HTML return by my application it is obvious that all the static content URLs for debug_toolbar are broken (404s).  All the other static content in the application works fine.

I can execute `./manage.py findstatic debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js` and it will find the debug_toolbar assets.

I have tried adding the static directory for debug_toolbar to the STATICFILES_DIR.

I have static finders in my settings.py file.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

I have tried the command `./manage.py collectstatic` which executes fine and in fact copies the static content from the debug_toolbar directories (stored in a virtual environment) to the same place all other static content is stored.

But none of this solves my problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Paul

Comment: Have you added it to your ```INSTALLED_APPS```? If so, have you tried going through the explicit setup? http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/installation.html#explicit-setup

Comment: Yep, I followed the explicit instructions so have it in INSTALLED_APPS.  Pretty sure this stuff is correct as the links/content exist in the page, just some weirdness with static content preventing it from rendering.